# why is two-way binding undefined in angularjs directive link function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to send data from controller to directive , but i am getting undefined why ?

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/0gtFynDdvyY0sWqKGI2l?p=preview

I do the following steps

```
  <div img-upload="" previewData="data" method="POST" 
       url="webfreaks.in/dummyService">
  </div>
```

`previewData="data"` send data in directive
in controller I defined like this

```
$scope.data =['sds']
```

but when i am trying to get its value in the directive . I am getting `undefined` **undefined**

why ?

```
link : function(scope,elem,attrs){
    var formData = new FormData();
    console.log(scope.previewData)
```

scope

```
scope : {
    url : "@",
    method : "@",
    previewData:'=',
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

previewData in template has to be like this 'preview-data' (use kebab-case for bindings in the template):

```
<div img-upload="" preview-data="data" method="POST" url="webfreaks.in/dummyService"></div>
```